# Changing the color of the indentation level in Vundle

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vundle

I would like to change the dots' color (that shows indentation level) in Vundle. I am using `t256` colorscheme in `~/.vimrc`. I was successful at changing the line number's color by changing the `LineNr` inside `~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors/colors/t256.vim`
, but I couldn't find the variable for the dots' color.

Thanks in advance

Abdul

Comment: You seem completely lost. Vundle is a plugin manager: it's not an environment or distribution or whatever where you make general settings for your editor.

Answer (score 1):

The feature responsible for displaying those dots is governed by two options: `list` and `listchars`. The documentation for `listchars` tells you what highlight groups to edit:

```
:help 'listchars'
```

By the way, if you copied your config from someone else it's not too late to go through it line by line and read the relevant `:help` pages.